# Per-Request static data in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, thread-safety, httpcontext

I'm wanting to cache the roles a user is in for each request that comes in. There are several places throughout any given page where where we have something like:

```
<% if(Roles.IsUserInRole("RoleName")) {%>
    <!-- Conditional Rendering -->
<% } else if(Roles.IsUserInRole("AnotherRole") {%>
    <!-- You get the point -->
<% } %>
```

Since this is all stored in a sql database, each of these requests hit the database. I know there are ways to cache the roles in a cookie, but I don't want to do that. Anyway, What I was thinking was something like this.

```
public static class SecurityUtils
    {
        public static string[] UserRoles()
        {
            var context = HttpContext.Current;

            if (context == null) return Enumerable.Empty<string>();

            string[] roles;

            roles = context.Items["UserRoles"] as string[];

            if (roles == null)
            {
                roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser();
                context.Items["UserRoles"] = roles;
            }

            return roles;
        }
    }
```

Anyone see any issues with this? I know that ever call to `UserRoles()` will lookup the item in the context and maybe this isn't the most effecient thing to do. What I really want to know is if this will cache it on a per-request basis so there's no overlap with other users request.

Comment: @bzlm - perhaps the roles are not `Serializeable`?

Comment: @Oded You're right. Maybe `string[]` in the code example in the question refers to rainbows and unicorns rather than sequences of letters and numbers.

Comment: @bzlm it wasn't a trick question like "Can you find out what's wrong with this?" and I know something that you don't. =)

Comment: @bzlm last time I checked though rainbows and unicorns ARE serializable.

Comment: @Micah Just wondering, since `Session` would be the obvious place to store the list of roles, unless you specifically want a per-request cache.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That looks safe enough at a quick glance. HttpContext.Current.Items is a per-HTTP request cache. Another option to consider to further reduce database calls would be to use session state.

Consider a scenario where you have a page with a lot of ajax stuff going on. Each ajax request will invoke a database call to load security roles, since they are all separate HTTP requests.

Comment: That's a great point about ajax requests and such. I'll probably use session, but just make sure it get's cleared if the user adds or changes roles.

Comment: I'll point out a probably obvious caveat to using a session to reduce database calls -- you can configure the actual session provider to be a database or external server (like Redis, AWS DynamoDb), so pay attention to how the environment is set up.

Comment: I know this is old, but I believe you meant `HttpContext` instead of `HttpContent`

Comment: Thanks @Davy8 I fixed the typo in the answer

Answer (score 3):

It will cache it per request, since you are using the current `HttpContext`.

If you were using a static member, it would be cached till the web application was recycled.

As such it looks fine - a fairly common pattern in fact (using a static member as an in-memory cache or the current `HttpContext`).

Comment: @Oded: Can you explain this: *This will be cached till the web application recycles.*?

Comment: My understanding was that HttpContext.Items is a per-request cache, is that not the case? I.e. http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/060904-1.aspx

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka - There is a default amount of time till a .NET web application resets itself. I mean until it is reset, either manually or automatically.

Comment: Ah, I see where you were going with your response. His static member is a method, not a field.

Comment: @Shan - yeah. Fixed on the `static` without seeing it was a method rather than a field.

Comment: @Oded: But it still doesn't explain why should not HttpContext instance and related Items provide per request cache and why should they live till web application recycles - at least this is my understanding of your answer.

Comment: @Ladislav - See the other comments, I thought he was using a static field as the cache. Your understanding is right and I have updated my answer.